# socket io client cannot connect to remote server (socket server)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Here is my socket server codes

```
const Path=require('path');
const Express=require('express');
const App=Express();
const Server=require('http').Server(App)
const SocketIO=require('socket.io')(Server)

App.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(Path.join(__dirname,'index.html'))
})

SocketIO.on('connection',socket=>{
    console.log('Connection approved')
})

Server.listen(3005,'127.2.0.1');
```

And here is my client code

```
<script src="http://127.2.0.1:3005/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

    var socket=io.connect('https://127.2.0.1',{port: 3005})
    console.log(socket)
    socket.on('connect',()=>{
        alert(1)
    })
    socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
        alert(2)
    })

</script>
```

Where is the problem ?

I just run server on 127.2.0.1 on port 3005 and socket client its not in node js server.
I just connect client using remote

Socket variable log is

```
Socket
acks: {}
connected: false
disconnected: true

and more ...
```

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in your browser console? Are you sure that _https_ works for your local server `io.connect("https://127.2.0.1")`, perhaps try using "http"?

Comment: No there is no error in my console and http or https both are not working